# SQL Server sp_columns does not return expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2014

I was trying to check the data types of each column.

I have tried the code below.

```
use AdventureWorks2014; 
exec sp_columns Person;
```

However, the result return something like this.

[image]

PS: I am using `AdventureWorks` sample database.

Comment: Is it a display issue in your ssms? What version of ssms are you using?

Comment: I'm using SSMS version 12.0.2000.8.

Comment: Is your issue that it's displaying the results as text? If so, try turning it on so that it displays in a grid (Ctrl+D).

Comment: Thank you very much ZLK. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 options available for the **Query Results**

- Results to Text <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
- Results to Grid <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- Results to File <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Currently your results are showing in Text mode. Changing it to Grid mode, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or simply select the option as in the screenshot below:

> [image: Results to Grid]

---

More over, if you are regularly using the `sp_columns` to get the column details, you can add it as keyboard shortcut by `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Query Shortcuts`.

In the `Options` you can place the `sp_columns` against the not reserved columns. For an example, I placed it against the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>.

So the next time when you type the tablename in the query analyzer and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>, you will get your expected result.

[image: Steps to add the shortcut]